# HttpPost [FromBody] parameter null when set to a specific object, but is not null when set to string and can be converted to that object in method

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public SearchDocumentRequest GetData([FromBody] SearchDocumentRequest request)
{

}
```

When I try to get data from one specific place in the app, `request` in this method is always null. However, I can retrieve request as a string, convert to SearchDocumentRequest and get the correct documents with this search query without any errors, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public SearchDocumentRequest GetData([FromBody] string request)
{
  var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchDocumentRequest>(request);

  ...
}
```

Why? What could possibly be the issue in the first case? Why is `request` null if it can be converted to the object?

Furthermore, this (first) method is used in many places throughout the app (at least 12 places), and only in one place there is an issue. I have checked the other jsons that make up the incoming requests, compared to json in this case, but I cannot find any difference or any issue. It's the exact same json, only two string values are different.

Comment: _"Why is request null if it can be converted to the object?"_ - we can only guess. Why don't you show your entire request? My best guess would be that it's missing a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: In addition to the above comment: check the (de)serialization settings. Chances are there's a difference between the _expected_ casing of the Json and the _actual_ casing. Probably PascalCase vs. camelCase.

Comment: @rick casing is pretty lax by default.

Comment: we need to see the JSON being sent and the code that makes the request using post

Comment: this is a bit of a hunch but try and use a different variable name e.g 'temp' I would guess that c# mvc is getting confused over the 'Request' variable that contains information about the request e.g POST/GET user agent etc